# Writing PHP functions that has many parameters/modifiers

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Please be patient and read the question carefully. So this is the demonstration what I do: PHP doesn't have ability to make overlapping functions. That are function that has same name but have different number of parameters. For example this is not possible in php but can be done in Java:

```
public class Testing() {

   public function doSometing() {
     // some useful code
   }

   public function doSometing(string $name) {
     // some useful code
   }

   public function doSometing(string $name, int type, string $connectedNews ) {
     // some useful code
   }         
}
```

Now in order to make a flexible function I saw there is a way to do this by using one function with the unique name that has a few necessary params and all other parameters are optional. If we have a lot of optional characters than we put them in the array called options:

```
public function getCateogries( $lang = null, $options = array() ) {

    }
```

If we have a lot of options that we are sending in array than the function becomes to ugly and very hard to read and use. I know for the php function "func_get_arg but" but I think it is not the best approach.

The question is:
Is there better approach to do this? Is there any pattern that solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Yes you could do that, but what is the question?

Comment: Read *what* question carefully?

Comment: It's called polymorphism. But yeah -- what you did is fine.

Comment: @eboix: I _believe_ the OP is using PHP to illustrate what is **not** possible.

Comment: Okay. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: Your "question" would be very useful to a lot more people if it took the form of a question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guess at a post without a real question. Maybe you can work with dynamic checking of arguments:

```php
function GuessWhoByHowManyMaybe () {
    $NumberOfArguments = func_num_args();

    # get each one
    $ArrayOfArguments = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $NumberOfArguments; $i++) {
        echo "Argument " . $i . " is: " . $ArrayOfArguments[$i] . "\n";
    }

    # or grab one, in particular, right away
    if ($NumberOfArguments >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "\n";
    }

    # example explained below this function
    if ($NumberOfArguments == 0) {
        // some useful code for when there are 0 arguments
    } elseif ($NumberOfArguments == 1) {
        // some useful code for when there is 1 argument
    }
}
```

You can make it act how you want by adding some code to check the number of parameters and then perform an action assuming that when a certain number of arguments are passed, then that means you can do a certain action. Err.. if you get what I mean...

Comment: Is there any better way to do this? Is there any pattern that will devide the code into several classess or functions etcc...?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to make a method with overloads. That is possible. There are two possible ways to do this easily.

The first is to set default values for your parameters as such:

```
<?php
    public function foo($value1, $value2 = "", $value3 = false, $value4 = 2) { ... }
?>
```

Now $value1 is mandatory while the others are optional. The second method involves an arrey where you check if certain keys are present. For instance:

```
<?php
    public function foo($params) { 
        if (array_key_exists('value1', $params) { ... do something ... }
        if (array_key_exists('value2', $params) { ... do something ... }
    }
?>
```

Both are generally accepted solutions and could also be used in combination.

Comment: I know what this is some kind of solution but it is not the best one. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class StupidJavaEnvySample {
    private function getMethodSignatureString($args) {
        return join('_', array_map('gettype', $args));
    }


    public function sayHi() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $callable = array($this, 'sayHi__' . $this->getMethodSignatureString($args));
        return call_user_func_array($callable, $args);
    }

    //use naming convention for the overloaded methods.
    private function sayHi__string_object($str, $obj) {
        echo 'so';
    }
    private function sayHi__array_array($arr1, $arr2) {
        echo 'aa';
    }
}

$o = new StupidJavaEnvySample();
$o->sayHi(array(), array());
```

my sample doesn't differentiate between different types of objects, but im sure you could pull that off with reflection. Anyway, php has little use for this because its a dynamic language.